# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

Tags: eclipse, wso2, classnotfoundexception, wso2-esb

I am using jdk 1.6.31 and when i add a server (WSO2 Carbon 3.0.1 based server) in eclipse and try to start the server it gives me the following error in the console:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Exception in thread "main"
```

WSO2 Carbon 3.2 based server  gets started but with this in the console:

```
No properties path set - looking for transactions.properties in classpath...
Using init file: /D:/naveenraj/wso2/Training%20Workouts/wso2esb-4.0.3/lib/transactions.properties
```

Is this a vital error?

I am new to WSO2 ESB.

Comment: Can you run the wso2server.bat located in wso2esb-4.0.3/bin/ to start the server? Is it successful? 
Probable reason is that Eclipse can't determine some system variables.

Comment: Yes I can run the wso2server.bat .........But I need to use the eclipse so please help me out.

Comment: What's the Carbon Studio version you are using? If you are not using v1.0.14, then update to it, and try.
http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/2010/10/install-carbon-studio-100-eclipse

Comment: Am using The version you mentioned KasunBG ..Is there any problem if I don't use apache maven or ant ..Both of them are not installed......

Comment: As of now I don't face any problems if i use the WSO2 Carbon 3.2 based server .....But there is only problem with the previous versions...I think we can ignore the WSO2 Carbon 3.2 based server based warnings....Can you solve the previous version problem..KasunBG

Answer (score 0):

I'm  not sure if this could help but make sure you defined JAVA_HOME and CARBON_HOME before starting the server

Good luck

Christophe

Comment: Hi,   I have set both JAVA_HOME and CARBON_HOME  but WSO2 Carbon 3.0.1 based server does not start with the above error but WSO2 Carbon 3.2 based server starts with ........................................
No properties path set - looking for transactions.properties in classpath... Using init file: /D:/.../wso2esb-4.0.3/lib/transactions.properties............in between